How to remove clear adhesive tape from wooden kitchen cupboards?
I have these annoying clear adhesive tape strips on a kitchen cupboard.
I tried the following to remove them:

Soap, then rub with pumice stone. It works but also scratches the
surfaces.
Heating it with a heat gun which should supposedly loosen the
adhesive. Does not work at all.
Rubbing isopropyl alcohol on it which should loosen the adhesive. Does not work

I think the correct description for the cupboard material is "Wood panel with a laminate finish" but I'm no expert in these matters.
Any ideas?



Apply a stickier tape, then peel?  Also, what kind of material is the cabinet surface?

Mild solvents like orange oil, alcohol, naphtha, mineral spirits, and WD40 could work to remove adhesive residue -- but they likely won't penetrate the plastic film of the tape. They'll work a little around the edges, and that might help you work the film up, but it could be slow going.
You might try a plastic razor blade for hand scraping or a rubber eraser wheel spun with a drill to help with the mechanical lift-the-film work. These are less likely to damage the cabinet surface compared to sharp metal scraping tools. (Fair disclosure: I have a rubber eraser wheel and don't love it; it seldom gets used. Maybe I've been using it wrong or for the wrong kinds of jobs.)
If residue is left behind it can be removed with the solvents mentioned above, or with the rapid stick-and-pull tape technique proposed by k_z.

Mineral spirits is the only solvent mentioned above that ever worked reliably for me; the so-called "scentless" (i.e. less stinky) variety is recommended.
